# XPage: OnClick Event Listbox don't work properly

Tags: xpages

I'm using a listbox on an xpage which is using computed values

```
<xp:listBox id="listboxAutorInstitution"
                        styleClass="listBoxPicklist">

                        <xp:selectItems>
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:getValuesPicklist("authorRT")}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:selectItems>
                        <xp:eventHandler event="ondblclick"
                            submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="ccAuthor">
                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:view.postScript("console.log('" + getComponent("listboxAuthor").value +"')")}]]></xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:listBox>
```

The values come from a rich-text field on a profiledocument.

```
function getValuesPicklist(fieldName) {
    var db: NotesDatabase = session.getCurrentDatabase();
    var doc: NotesDocument = db.getProfileDocument("(Config)", "");

   var list = @Trim(doc.getFirstItem(fieldName).getValueString().split("|"));
        return list.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
        });

    }
```

If I load the xpage on browser and clicking an element from listbox the console.log('') script is only run for some elements.

The trace log shows me the following error message:

**Validation Error: Value is not valid**

What could be the cause for this behaviour?

**SOLVED:**
I solved the problem by using

doc.getFirstItem(fieldName).getUnformattedText().split("|");

instead of

doc.getFirstItem(fieldName).getValueString().split("|");

Comment: This error usually happens in validation phase, when submitted value (full/partial refresh) does not match the options list.

Comment: What can I do to prevent this error?

Comment: update your question with samples of good and bad keywords. analyze what are their differences. snoop for submitted values (dev tools in browser) - do they differ from what is shown? special characters may be the cause (deducing from your `localeCompare` call. it depends...

Comment: "Research and Innovaion" is valid and "National Meterology Institute" is not valid. I can't find the difference between this keywords. There is also no difference in invisible characters

Comment: If I duplicate a keyword which produces an error, the new keyword don't produce the error.  Is there the possibility to disable the validation phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see my Update in the question post!

Answer (score 0):

Based on discussion:

1) You can disable validation: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPagesNoDataValidation.htm

I am not sure it will help with listbox, though.

2) Seems, there is something wrong with that profile - my guess is "enter" or some invisible character somewhere at the beginning or end of some keywords (very common with copy/paste from other sources). Try to cut everything, paste to notepad, and copy/paste back.

By the way, it is pretty odd to use Rich Text field to keep keywords...

Comment: I have got a problem with the 64k limit of text-fields